# How to concate strings in assembly lamguage for 8086 in nasm

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16

**I tried :-**

```
[org 0x100] 


data segment

fn db 'Atul$'

ln db 'Dagur$'

data ends

code segment

mov ax,@data
mov ds,ax
mov ah, 
mov bh, ln
add ah,bh
add ah, '$'

lea dh,ah
   
;output the string
;loaded in dx 
mov AH,0x09
int 0x21

code ends

mov ax,0x4c00
int 0x21
```

but it gives me the error like

**instruction excepted
data redefined**

Please tell me the desired answer and also whats wrong in my code

Comment: You are trying to create a `.COM` file with two segments. But the (ancient) `.COM` file format only allows one segment. But this is only one error. At which line does the error occur?

Comment: `data ends` - that's MASM syntax.  NASM doesn't need a line to declare the end of a section or segment: that line will be parsed the same as `data: ends`, i.e. trying to define a symbol called `data`.  The same symbol was already defined by the line `data segment`, which parsed as `data: segment`, because in NASM `segment` is the directive, so `segment .data` is what you'd normally do to switch to the .data section/segment.  (But as @zx485 said, .com is a flat binary, so just put your data at the end, not at the top where it will get executed as instructions.)

Comment: You get this symbol-conflict error before NASM even gets to the point of complaining about the fact that `segment` and `ends` aren't valid instruction mnemonics or macros you've defined.

Comment: "Please tell me the desired answer"?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "concate strings"? Is the desired output to take as input two pointers to ('$' terminated?) strings and copy them both to a third memory buffer (also '$' terminated)?  Or to write both strings sequentially to the console? Or something else?